# Recursion vs For loops - Factorials, Java

Tags: java, recursion, for-loop

Which of these two methods of getting a factorial (loop vs recursive) is more efficient/faster? and if that one can be improved, how so?

Language: Java

```
private static long factrecur(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n * factrecur(n-1);
    }

}

private static long factloop(int a) {
    long total = 1;
    for (int b=a;b>=1;b--) {
        total *= b;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: `total *= hi;` - what is `hi`?

Comment: Did you benchmark them? What did that tell you?

Comment: Oh sorry nideo, I was renaming the variables on the text editor, forgot to change it. I'm not sure how to benchmark, but i'll look it up.

Comment: Rather than b>=1 say b>0 as there are usually low level instructions to compare with 0 which will make the code quicker

Comment: for loops are certainly better than recursion, plus you could end up in a stackoverflow (no pun intented :) ) in the latter case in n is very large.

Comment: In the loop, you don't need to multiply by 1. Using `;b>1;` is enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The for loop will be more efficient because there is no overhead of the method calls. (As a general rule loops are almost always more efficient than recursion)

To explain why you have to get into the nitty gritty details of what happens when you call a method and something called the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Basically when you call a method it needs a bit of space to work with (for things like its local variables etc) it also needs space for the incoming parameters being passed to it and a place to store the return address of where it should go when it is done executing. This space is dynamically provided by 'pushing' the values on to a stack. That stack space remains occupied until the method returns at which point it is 'popped off'.

So think about recursion in this context: every time you call the method from within itself you push more data onto the stack, without returning from the method you were in (and thus without freeing up the stack space the calling method was occupying). As your recursion goes deeper the amount of memory increases.

In contrast the for loop you wrote just uses the fixed amount of memory provided by one stack frame push.

Comment: Of course unless you use some functional language and profit from tail recursion.

Comment: A call on long will overrun with `factorial (21)`, which is a small number, to get a significant performance problem. For higher numbers, the code will fail - for very frequent calls, a hashmap will be faster than repeated loops. Multiple calls on BigInteger might still be faster with a hashmap behind the scene. Don't forget: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Yes yes you all are raising extremely valid points, but I also think that you are over engineering things a bit. I suspect Deley isn't really looking to find the best way to calculate factorials but really just looking for some help with his homework...

Comment: Oh, it seems I have forgotten about this post. The question was not homework, I am learning java on my own accord.

Answer (score 4):

With 21 calls, your long will **overrun**, which is very early to measure a difference, which could get relevant.

You might need **BigInteger** to measure a significant difference, when measuring `factorial (10*1000*1000)` or something that large. If you don't have *high numbers* to calculate, but calculate low factorials *often*, a hashmap with precalculated values will be faster than recursion **and** looping.

Comment: +1: I would say; check that performance matters before worrying about it.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem with recursion is that every time that the function is called it's address is put on the top of the stack, concatenating a lot of call can cause a **stack overflow** exception if the number of recursion calls is high .